# wifi not working, lenovo G50-70

Tags: linux, wifi

I have just installed UBUNTU 16.04 LTS/

I have problem with Wifi.

I can't  enable wifi in my laptop. I have lenovo G50-70.

```
iwconfig
enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

The output for `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
*-network
UNCLAIMED
```

network-manager is already the newest version (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2).

It's showing me only bluetooth and nothing about wireless.

```
rfkill list all
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have Windows 8.1 on this computer too and wifi is working properly.

```
lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:9c14] (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:9c16] (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller [8086:9c43] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:9c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)`
```

```
lspci | grep -i wireless
```

I don't get any respond.

```
lspci
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Vendor's name:

```
product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
vendor: Broadcom Corporation
```

I found: Broadcom BCM43142 Wireless LAN Driver (802.11b/g/n) for Windows 7 (32-bit, 64-bit) - Notebook

https://support.lenovo.com/pl/en/downloads/DS033286

Comment: network-manager is already the newest version (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2).

Comment: Please don’t post clarifying information in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.   And please don’t post text in languages other than English (unless it’s absolutely essential to the question, and even then you should include an English translation.)

Comment: The output above shows that your wireless card is not being detected at all. It should show up in `iwconfig` and there would probably be corresponding soft and hard `rfkill` locks.

Comment: Broadcom [43142 is not supported by the open drivers](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43), you will have to install the proprietary drivers from broadcom (`wl`), and hope these support your card properly.

Comment: I believe you want to install the ubuntu package named `bcmwl-kernel-source`, but as I don't use ubuntu, I can't confirm.

Answer (score 2):

First, find out the vendor and model of your wireless interface:

```
lspci | grep -i wireless
```

After you have the vendor's name, you may be able to use `apt-get` in order to install the required firmware (easy way), or you have to do some googling in order to get the kernel module and insert it yourself (`modprobe` command).

Lenovo laptops/hardware are usually simple to set up Linux on.

Also, please be 100% sure the power switch to the wireless interface is not off!

Comment: I don't know where is my power swich to the wireless interface. I do some googling F5 and Fn+F5 only refresh and Fn+F7 Pressing F7 turns Caret Browsing on or off.

Comment: If your wireless interface does not show up at all under lspci, the OS does not even know it's there. There's a rather good chances it's simply disabled (i.e powered off), and therefore not showing up. Pleas issue "sudo dmesg |grep -i wifi" and "sudo dmesg |grep -i wireless" to see what that brings up.

Comment: "sudo dmesg |grep -i wifi" and "sudo dmesg |grep -i wireless" 
I don't get any respond.

Comment: okay, in this case, your OS certainly has no knowledge of the wireless interface. If you have a live CD of that same OS, try booting from it and see if you have better luck. Here's a case (from MS windows), over there, it was solved by installing an additional Lenovo software tool, from there, they were able to re-enable the wireless adapter (It's not much help in your case, I know), but sheds more light, none the less. https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/Lenovo-G50-70-Wi-Fi-problem-in-64bit-windows-7-wireless/td-p/2047866

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```